# EntityFramework - One to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have a one-to-many relationship between MapHeader and MapDetail tables
therefore there can be multiple mapdetails for a single mapheader.
In the database, table **MapDetail** has foreign key MapHeaderID which maps to the pk(MapHeaderId) in **MapHeader** table.

I have defined it in EntityFramework Code-first as follows:

```
public class MapHeader
{
    public int MapHeaderID { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<MapDetail> mapDetails
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
 }

public class MapDetail
{
    public int MapDetailID { get; set; }
    public int MapHeaderID { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual MapHeader mapheader { get; set; }
}
```

**FLUNETAPI**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MapDetail>()
            .HasRequired<MapHeader>(md => md.mapheader)
            .WithMany(mh => mh.mapDetails)
            .HasForeignKey(md => md.MapHeaderID);
```

It does not link!! my mapheader property inside mapdetail record/object is still null...What am i doing wrong?

**CODE - WRITTEN IN RAZOR VIEW**

```
foreach (MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
   {
     if(...)
     {
       if(...){...}
       else{
          <td>
          foreach(..)
          {
              var term = geMapDetail.Term == 0 ? geMapDetail.mapheader.Term : geMapDetail.Term;
          }
          </td>
       }
     }
```

the code crashes on the above geMapDetail.mapheader since mapheader is null

My query is in a stored procedure

```
select distinct md.yearid, md.assessmentid, md.resulttypeid,
    concat(ah.name, ' - ', a.name) as Name, md.term, md.semester, md.month, md.week,
   md.MapDetailID, md.MapHeaderID, md.ColourFormatType, md.ResultTypeIDs,
    md.RowOrder, md.Attendance, md.EffectSize, md.Growth, md.IndicatorID,
    md.TeacherNameRequired, md.AllowEdit, md.PageHeaderID, md.IncludePreviousTerms,
    md.IncludePreviousSemesters, y.year
from mapdetail md
left outer join assessments a on a.assessmentid = md.assessmentid
left outer join assessments ah on ah.assessmentID = a.headerID
left outer join years y on md.yearID = y.yearID
left outer join assessmentresulttypes art on a.assessmentid = art.assessmentid
left outer join resulttypes rt on rt.resulttypeid = art.resulttypeid
where  md.mapheaderid = 22;
```

**DBCONTEXT**

```
 public MapDetailResultSet Find_MapDetails(int mapHeaderId, int yearId, string classIds, int indicatorGroup, string indicatorIds)
    {
        var query = "CALL Find_MapDetails(@mapHeaderId, @yearId, @classIds, @indicatorGroup, @indicatorIds)";

        MySqlParameter[] mySqlParams = new MySqlParameter[] { new MySqlParameter("mapHeaderId", mapHeaderId),
                                                                new MySqlParameter("yearId", yearId),
                                                                new MySqlParameter("classIds", classIds),
                                                                new MySqlParameter("indicatorGroup", indicatorGroup),
                                                                new MySqlParameter("indicatorIds", indicatorIds)
                                                            };

        MapDetailResultSet mapdetails = new MapDetailResultSet();

        using (var multiResultSet = DbContextExtensions.MultiResultSetSqlQuery(this, query, mySqlParams))
        {
            mapdetails.mapDetails = multiResultSet.ResultSetFor<MapDetail>().ToList();
            //other result sets
            ...

        }
  return mapdetails;
  }
```

I have also disabled lazyloading in  DBContext: (didnt help)

```
 public geContext(string connString):base(connString) 
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
select distinct md.yearid, md.assessmentid, md.resulttypeid,
    concat(ah.name, ' - ', a.name) as Name, md.term, md.semester, md.month, md.week,
   md.MapDetailID, md.MapHeaderID, md.ColourFormatType, md.ResultTypeIDs,
    md.RowOrder, md.Attendance, md.EffectSize, md.Growth, md.IndicatorID,
    md.TeacherNameRequired, md.AllowEdit, md.PageHeaderID, 
    md.IncludePreviousTerms,
    md.IncludePreviousSemesters, y.year
   from mapdetail md
   left outer join assessments a on a.assessmentid = md.assessmentid
   left outer join assessments ah on ah.assessmentID = a.headerID
   left outer join years y on md.yearID = y.yearID
   left outer join assessmentresulttypes art on a.assessmentid = art.assessmentid
   left outer join resulttypes rt on rt.resulttypeid = art.resulttypeid
   left outer join mapheader mh on mh.mapheaderID = md.mapheaderID
    where  md.mapheaderid = 22;
```

Comment: Are you allowing null in MapDetail Table ?

Comment: no my mapheaderid in mapdetail has a value 22 which can be found in the mapheader table

Comment: i am using stored procedure though to load the mapdetail this should not be the problem i am sure

Comment: So the tables are set up correctly in the database and have actual data. But when you query a `MapDetail`, the `mapheader` property is `null`. Correct? In that case, i assume you're using lazy loading and you have to tell EF to actually load the `MapHeader` too. Can you show the code you use to query the data?

Comment: ok sure lemme update my post

Comment: done..i have tried to make it simple by removing extra code

Comment: Do you have lazy loading turned off in your DbContext?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: my understanding is that lazy loading is done whenever i need to use the data for instance here when i am using the mapheader then it should load mapheader right away

Comment: Turning it off would be in your DbContext class. Can you show your code for that?

Comment: code is added this function Find_MapDetails is inside dbcontext class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the ideal way to do but it got me through anyway..
i loaded the particular mapheader from the repository and then populated each mapdetail object in the list manually

**Controller**

```
   MapHeaderRepository repMapHeader = new MapHeaderRepository("name=ge");
   MapDetailsRepository repMapDetail = new MapDetailsRepository("name=ge");

   MapDetailResultSet mapDetailResultSet = repMapDetail.FindMapDetails(mapHeaderId, yearId, classIds, 
                                                    indicatorGroup, indicatorIds);
   var mapHeader = repMapHeader.Get(22);

   foreach (MapDetail md in mapDetailResultSet.mapDetails)
   {
        md.mapheader = mapHeader;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me with just your model classes. You don't even need the FluentAPI code because your class definition is following the Code-First foreign key convention. I used these model classes:

```
public class MapHeader
{
    public int MapHeaderId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MapDetail> MapDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MapDetail
{
    public int MapDetailId { get; set; }

    public int MapHeaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual MapHeader MapHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote a simple command line program to save some data and read it back from the database:

```
private static void InsertMapHeader()
{
    var header = new MapHeader
    {
        MapDetails = new List<MapDetail>
        {
            new MapDetail(),
            new MapDetail(),
            new MapDetail(),
            new MapDetail()
        }
    };

    using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
    {
        context.MapHeaders.Add(header);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private static void ReadMapDetails()
{
    using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
    {
        var detail = context.MapDetails.FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Header id: {0}", detail.MapHeader.MapHeaderId);
    }
}
```

This code gets the first MapDetail and follows the navigation property to MapHeader. All of this work fine with no issue because Code-First is using lazy loading to get the MapHeader navigation property when it's asked for.

If you want to eagerly load the dependent property, you can change your query to use the Include method to join the MapHeaders table, like this:

```
var detail = context.MapDetails.Include(d => d.MapHeader).FirstOrDefault();
```

You're still not showing the code for your query (it's probably in your Control class), so it's hard to say what the exact issue might be.

Comment: pedro i have added my query too this query is in a stored procedure

Comment: also i cannot find the Include method in my resultset EF v 6.1.3

Comment: Ok, don't turn off lazy loading. With the stored procedure, you need to join the MapHeader table into your results (like your joined the other tables) so that EF will create that Navigation property as well.

Comment: you mean in the query..ok

Comment: Yes, in your query.

Comment: no it didnot work..the only way left could be to select the mh.term etc in the select list of query in which case the mapdetail entity definition would not match!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139914/discussion-between-samra-and-pedro-silva).