# How could I return all records from a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am using this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @pSelect nvarchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'select ' + @pSelect + ' from vwAcdAdmissionWithvwAcdAdmissionSessionDetailWithAllMaster';
     EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

and executing it from c#.net entitydatamodel with linq

shoolSoulDataEntites db = new schoolSoulDataEntites; 
var ss = db.Myprocedure("column1,column2");

but it is returning a integer value
i want all records of the result of procedure
plss help me

Comment: what is `myprocedure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583933/creating-entities-from-stored-procedures-which-have-dynamic-sql

Comment: myprocedure is a storedprocedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it is returning a integer value

No, it is not returning an integer value.

It is the method that you are calling that is returning you integer value. I guess you are calling ExecuteScalar to execute store procedure. You need to change it to executeNonQuery and use some dataadapter to fill up your dataset/datatable.

Comment: i am doing it from linq using entitydata model

Comment: add in the complete method in your question.