# how to set return type of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am using this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @pSelect nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'Select'  + @pSelect + ' from '
tabel1;
    Exec sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

it is returning me a integer type value
i want it to return a value of type tabel1

is it possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I return all records from a stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481937/how-could-i-return-all-records-from-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    (@pSelect nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @pSelect from Table1

END
```

Call the stored procedure as:

```
exec MyProcedure 'field_name'
```

I hope this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am executing this sql query from C#.net code not from sql query

Comment: Well, then call the SP from C# code along field_name as the parameter.

Comment: i am doing the same calling the stored procedure from the parameter but it is not returning the result

Comment: Are you sure you are using a dataset for the retrieved data? Show the c# code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , SP DON'T RETURNS VALUES UNLESS YOU ARE USING OUT PARAMETERS

REGARDS

ASHUTOSH ARYA

Comment: is there any other option for this

Comment: @user2445111: I am not sure why is this happening. generally it works,  is it like you are getting number of rows in out put ? also u said you are using this via C#, did you tried executing this sp from back end ?