# How create complex type for result set returned as temp table from stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, edmx

How to get Columns of a temp table which contains multiple table columns returned from stored procedure in entity framework  function import?.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First Step:**

At first you have to create a normal store procedure **without using temp table**. this store procedure will contain all the column name (normal table+temp table). Now will be able to create the complex type in your **EDMX**

**Second Step :**

Now you will modify your  store procedure as you exactly want to write **using temp table**

**Third Step :**

Update the your **EDMX** model

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the data contract to the sql server so that entity framework can use it to generate the complex object. So we will use a dummy select statement to provide the contract. The select statement will be unreachable, so there is no performance penalty for the block of code.

Let's look at an example now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dummy_SP_Complex_Object_For_Temp_Table]   
AS
BEGIN

      IF 1 = 2 BEGIN
       SELECT
       cast(null as int)  as WeekNumber,
       cast(null as date)    as FilterStartDate,
       cast(null as date)    as FilterEndDate,
       cast(null as int)    as OrderNumber
        WHERE 1 = 2  
      END

  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', '#OrderShipments') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #T; 
  Create Table #OrderShipments
  (
    WeekNumber int,
    FilterStartDate date,
    FilterEndDate date,
    OrderNumber int
  )
  Select WeekNumber, FilterStartDate, FilterEndDate, OrderNumber FROM #OrderShipments order by WeekNumber
END
```

The first block of code is unreachable by the entity framework but it provides necessary information for the EF to create the complex type object.