# Update Wizard (Entity Framework) - VSS 2008 not updating view. Should I manually update it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, updatemodel

I am using VSS 2008 and built a Entity Framework model from SQL server 2008 database. Everything worked fine. Now I have updated a view to include a new column and tried refreshing the entire model from DB but the updated column in the view is not visible.

I opened the EDMX as XML to see the problem and it has a warning ...
 *Errors Found During Generation:
      warning 6002: The table/view 'Internet.dbo.XYZ' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.*

My question is, how do I FORCE the new column from this view to be added to my model. Can I update the EDMX manually to include this column as a property to the view entity. However, this could be a tedious task and is probably not guaranteed as a fix. Should I delete this view and then re-add it, but I read someones post that when he tried to re-add the object, it didn't allow him?

Thanks.

Comment: similar issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view-question