# What is the equivalent of DataContext in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Linq to SQL has this very simple model: DataContext and attributes [Table] and [Column] and no need for a config file.

But I understand Linq2SQL does not have a future.

How do I do something equivalent in entity framework?

(Equivalent = no config file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF 4.1 Code-First you can configure your mapping in a fluent way as opposed to a config file.

It is convention based so it will infer lot of thing from your model (eg: Table column are automatically mapped to properties if both names match).[EF Code First Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: Does it support view? What about if my table doesn't have a key?

Comment: it does support views. for tables without keys please look at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key

Answer (score 1):

In EF also we create a context from edmx file through which you can access all the entities(tables in Database). Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) article in msdn.

It also adds the connection string to the config file. If you just want to use entities then you dont need a config entry.

But EF is used with database operations most of the time.

Comment: I understand you are saying it does not exist?