# Teradata to Oracle Migration

Tags: sql, oracle11g, teradata

I'm new to Teradata,working in Teradata to Oracle migration project, converting Teradata DDL to Oracle.

For UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( TRSY_ID,TRSY_STM,TAX_ID ): converted like below

TRSY_ID as Primary key , TRSY_STM as not null Unique , TAX_ID as not null Unique.

How to convert the below 2 concepts into oracle:

1. PRIMARY INDEX ( TRSY_STM,TRSY_ID,TAX_ID );
2. SPNS_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
          (START WITH 1 
           INCREMENT BY 1 
           MINVALUE 1 
           MAXVALUE 999999999999999 
           NO CYCLE)

Any of your help is appreciated...

-Thanks

Sakthi

Comment: The answer to the identity part is here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464396/add-a-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table-in-oracle).  You need to create something called a "sequence" in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Teradata the Primary Index determines how the data is hash distributed across the AMPS. Thus it can serve to enforce the natural logical primary key and/or provide the fastest access or join path for the data. Therefore in your physical implementation of the Oracle data model you may wish to consider what indexing strategies would be necessary to support the access path or join path these columns provided.