# Oracle SQL - Add Primary Key to table

Tags: sql, oracle, key, addition

I have some columns with no primary key and **want to add a primary key column**.

```
NAME    Age
-------------
Peter   45
Bob     25
John    56
Peter   45
```

***Some collegues suggest to add a PK with a sequences and triggers***:
[Add a auto increment primary key to existing table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464396/add-a-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table-in-oracle)

This is nice, but ***my customers use a Database User with no rights to add sequences or triggers***.
I want to prevent to contact dozens of DBA administrators to alter user rights or to run my scripts.

***This is my suggestion to add a PK with only an update statement: (I need help in Step 2)***

*Step 1:* Create the ID column (*I have DB rights for this*)

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD ID NUMBER(10,0);
```

*Step 2:* **Question: Can I initialize the ID column with unique values based on the order of the rows or something else? How?**

```
UPDATE PERSON SET ID = something-unique
```

*Step 3:* Add the primary key contraint afterwords: (*I DB have rights for this*)

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

*Step 4:* Afterwords: the primary key is managed and added by my application.

This will be the result:

```
ID(PK)  NAME    Age
---------------------
1       Peter   45
2       Bob     25
3       John    56
4       Peter   45
```

Thanks folks!

Comment: WW gives the method for populating the PK based on a sequential number, but in your question you say, "... based on the order of the rows". Do you have a defined order for the rows, such as a "created_at" timestamp?

Comment: I have updated my text with a more clear question. Thanks WW!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Update person set id = rownum;
```

Answer (score 1):

THis idea is very childish, but should work fine if your table doesnot have large amount of rows.

For step 2, run a for loop like:

```
declare
    i pls_integer :=1;
     begin
    for rec in (select name,age, rowid from table_name)
    loop
    update table_name set id = i 
    where 
     table_name.name=rec.name 
     and table_name.age=rec.age 
     and table_name.rowid = rec.rowid;
    i:=i+1;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Arnab: You got goal of the problem correct, but this solution will not work. Even for a limited database with in my example 100 users, i could have 2 times: John - Age 56. The update above would then generate an identical primary key. But the solution above gives a different primary. Thanks for thinking together!

Comment: Okk.. i didnt know you would have duplicate rows.. I have modified my answer, so it should work now. However, ideally,I dont think you should have duplicate rows in your table

Comment: Arnab: Thanks. Your answer is now working. I have added a duplicate row in my question, based on your feedback. Nice work.

Comment: why is the idea childish?