# No matching unique or primary key for this column-list in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have created PERSON table in Oracle by this SQL syntax:

```
 Create table person
 (
 p_id int not null,
 personName char(5) not null );
```

Then I am trying to create ORDERS table with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES person(p_id) );
```

But I am getting the following error .

```
No matching unique or primary key for this column-list.
```

What is the problem ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Do you mean [oracle] or [mysql]?  Although Oracle Corporation owns MySQL (since it bought Sun) we reserve the [oracle] tag for the actual Oracle RDBMS, which is a different product.

Comment: After due consideration the posted error message is an Oracle one, ORA-02270, so I have removed the [mysql] tag.  Please revert if you want an answer for both databases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+No+matching+unique+or+primary+key+for+this+column-list

Answer (score 1):

Add primary key to person table:

```
 CREATE TABLE person(
   p_id int not null,
   personName char(5) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (p_ID)
 );
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/426ce/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys enforce a one-to-many relationship.  That is, however many records there are in the dependent table they can only reference a single record in the parent table.  This means the referenced column(s) in the parent table must be constrained by a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key.

The error message is telling you that there is no such constraint on `person(p_id)`.  And lo! if we compare the two DDL statements you have posted we can see that you have created a primary key for ORDERS but not for PERSON.

The solution is simple: constrain P_ID by adding a primary key to PERSON.  You can either drop and re-create the table, or you can use an `alter table` statement [to add a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19807314/146325).

Answer (score 0):

You should add primary key to person table.
try this:

ALTER TABLE Person
ADD CONSTRAINT p_id PRIMARY KEY (p_id);