# Entity Framework 5 DB-first association on a non-primary key field error

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Suppose I have the following 3 tables in an Oracle DB:

**TABLE1:**

```
Table1Id    Field1    Field2    Field3
```

With `Table1Id` as the primary key, but `Field1` also being unique and could be made a primary key, even though it isn't defined as such in my DB.

**Table2:**

```
Table2Id    Field1    Field4    Field5
```

With `Table2Id` as the primary key and `Field1` matching the values from `Field1` from `Table1`.

**Table3:**

```
Table3Id   Table1Id   Field6
```

With `Table3Id` as the primary key and `Table1Id` matching the value from `Table1Id` from `Table1`.

---

So, I create an entity framework 5 DB-first model (can't do EF 6 because it seems the Oracle model isn't supported yet in that version) and am able to easily create the association between `Table3` and `Table1`, but now I want to create the association between `Table2` and `Table1`.

I found that if I add `Field1` as a primary key in `Table1` (had to do so by editing the XML for the EDMX file since I otherwise get an error just using the GUI), then I get an issue setting the association since now that there are 2 primary keys, it wants me to map both to fields in `Table2`. If I leave the association from `Table1` > `Table1Id` as blank and only fill in the association for `Table1` > `Field1` to `Table2` > `Field1`, I get the a [111 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331531/properties-referred-by-the-principal-role-app-must-be-exactly-identical-to-the-k).

I am still VERY new to Entity Framework... I hope I explained my question well, but I have no clue how to overcome this... I've seen some answers that say it can't be done in EF4, but is there a way in the later version?

Any help at all (please remember I'm an EF newbie!!) would REALLY be appreciated!!

Comment: Can you add `Table1Id` to Table2?

Comment: I, unfortunately, have no control over the source DB... I can query it, but **nothing else**...

Comment: It seems to me that you have to declare Field1 as a PK for Table2. You can then set a relation between table1 and table2. But if, in the same context, you need and relation Table1(Field1) <-> Table2(Field1) and Table2(Table2Id) <-> TableX(TableXId), then you are in trouble (except by writing linq query and set the relation by hand through joins)

Comment: Yeah, thanks @tschmit007, that's exactly the problem... I simplified the problem, but each of these tables is connected to others via their corresponding primary keys... I was hoping there was something I didn't know in EF to do this... As fo rthe Linq solution, I'm guessing that's how I'll go, but then I'm no longer dealing with EF, right?

Comment: in my knowledge, at this time EF does not allow to address simply scenario with 2 PK for a table. I face similar case and, in my case, can use two contexts.

Comment: if you are in read only, and can create a view, you can use a vTable2 instead of table and build vtable2 to expose Table1Id

Comment: I like that idea! - Since I have no way to create the view in the DB itself, I used a defining query (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730307.aspx). I'm playing around with it now, but could / would this work??