# Insert operation in Ef with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am a beginner in Entity framework   and I want to insert operation through Linq To entity.

My code:

```
databaseentity entity = new databaseentity();
car c = new car { name = TextBox1.Text };
```

But when I write `Addobject` in code it shows error and this method is not supported by Ef:

```
entity.cars.AddObject(c);
```

How can I resolve this problem? I have already added `system.data.objects` namespace.

Comment: What is the exact message and stack trace?

Comment: have you done `entity.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
entity.AddToCars(c);
entity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it shows error      **Unable to update the EntitySet 'cars' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.**

Comment: have you added a primary key to your table in the database?

Comment: EF won't work with a table without Primary key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key