# entity framework without primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model

I have created an entity class for my mvc application. But, my table doesn't have a primary key and the VS throws back an error:

"The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view."

Is there a way to still use the model even if it has no primary key??
or Do I have to add a pk? or should I just use execute command?

Any suggestion/comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: table without primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key)

Comment: I recommend you adding the primary key to the table, there's no pro about not having a PK on table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just added a PK. I can now use my model. :)

Comment: @Guillelon, the question should be more like is the a real need of a PK? Adding a column to a table is not free, it has a cost in terms of space.

Comment: @Krige in my humble opinion the need is to avoid the process of not having a PK and using EF.