# Entity framework marks every field as an "entity key" on tables without any keys set

Tags: entity-framework

For tables with keys, everything works fine.  However, for a table without any keys, every field is marked as an "entity key".  Also, if I add keys to a table and then update entity framework, nothing changes.  Every field is still set as an entity key in entity framework.

Comment: In Entity Framework each table needs a primary key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key

Comment: Every table *should have* a proper primary key anyway ....

Comment: Are you sure you mean table and not View?  EF treats all non-nullable fields in a view as a primary key.

Comment: It's definitely a table.  I guess EF treats tables and views in the same way in this regard.