# Code first List of a ComplexType doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, complextype

I have searched and been unable to find any information about using a `List<MyComplexType>`. It's a 0-to-many relationship that I'm looking for.

I am doing code first design using EF6 and I have a complex type setup like this:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Image
{
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

When I add this to another model like this:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    //User Profile properties 
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

And then create a new migration and update the database I do not see any information about `Images` anywhere if I look at the database diagram. There are no association tables, nothing - it seems like it's being ignored.

However when I change the `UserProfile` class to look like this:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    //User Profile properties 
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

And then look at the database diagram I see these columns:

```
   //Bunch of other columns, name, address, etc.
   Image_Name
   Image_Bytes
   Image_ContentType
```

Is there anyway that I can do a `List<MyComplextType>`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Images table, you'll also need to add it to your data context. Something like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

(You should also add a primary key to your Image class. And on your UserProfile class, Images should be defined as `public virtual ICollection<Image>`)

Comment: I am not trying to get the Images table, rather I as hoping that a `ComplexType` would work as a `List` - normally a complex type that isn't a list will add all of those properties to whatever table you put that type on, but for a list I was hoping it would generate some sort of association table or something. Your answer would certainly be correct if I were trying to get an entire table out of images.

Comment: I admit, I wasn't familiar with ComplexType before, so I've researched it a bit since yesterday. If I am understanding it correctly, I don't think EF supports having a collection of a ComplexType on your table. You'd have to model it as a separate table. See this other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878961/ef-6-mapping-complex-type-collection