# ADO.net Entity Data Model from SQL Server

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to create an Entity Data Model from a SQL Server database using ADO.net in Visual Studio 2012 and I am facing an error that is about the key (primary and foreign):

> The table/view 'database.tablename' does not have a primary key
>   defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a
>   read-only table/view.

Is there anyone to help me for solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does database.tablename not have a primary key, and why can you not create one for it?

Comment: It is a view now, so that I can not create a primary key on a view. But I should use this view for data model.

Comment: Then, there are a number of suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key