# EF Code First From DB not creating Entities for all tables

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an existing Database I am trying to use `Entity Framework Code First From Database` to generate C# entities for. To do this I am doing `Add -> New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code First from database` inside Visual Studio 2015. When I go though the `Entity Data Model Wizard` I see that every table is selected but when the import finishes entities for some of the tables where not created. I have tried this twice and double checked that the table with no entities are indeed selected for import. No errors are thrown during the import so I am not sure why some of the tables are missing there entitles. What might be going wrong and how do I get an entities for every single selected table?

SQL Create Table Code for one of the missing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProgramControl] (
    [CodeName]    VARCHAR (80) NULL,
    [CodeValue1]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [CodeValue2]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [CodeValue3]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [CodeValue4]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Description] TEXT         NULL
);
```

Comment: What kind of tables are not being recreated? Linking tables (two columns of foreign keys used to represent many-to-many relationships)? Show us the table definitions for those tables that don't make it through the tool. I suspect they're simply not required and can be represented via collections in the entities at the other ends of the FK relationships.

Comment: @spender added some code for you. They are not linking tables and they are required as I need to query data out of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EF code-first requires the use of a primary key on every entity, so the tool is not able to map these tables.

It looks like you [might be able to work around this with some trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key), but adding a PK to every table is almost certainly the best approach.

Comment: So what are my options? I can't modify the database to add a PK to the tables. I have never used anything but EF to connect to and query DBs in ASP.Net

Answer (score 4):

If Table does not have at least one parameter not null ADO.NET will not generate the class. I don't know if it is a bug, just happened  to me.
It is not necessary to have a primary key but a not null.