# How to create table without primary key in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an old database which has some tables without primary key. Now I'm moving my old project to Asp.Net Core and using Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 Code First approach. I have made the model class of table and trying to add migration using `Add-Migration`, but it gives the below error. I think technically its expected behavior, But what are other alternative ways so that I don't need to modify the existing table schema.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'TestTable' requires
>   a primary key to be defined.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(ServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1
>   factory)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) The entity type 'TestTable' requires a primary key to be
>   defined.

**Model class:**

```
public class TestTable
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Col3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Col4 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Col5 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Col6 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Col7 { get; set; }
}
```

I have thought one solution like to add an autoincrement identity column as PK. Please suggest a good and proper way to do this?

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your solution of adding an auto-increment identity column as PK would work very much fine for you as per EF require PK to be able to uniquely identify each record and is very much necessary for insert and update operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: table without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key)

Comment: You can try EF Core 2.1 [Query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) when released. According to the documentation, one of their usage scenarios are *"Mapping to tables that do not have a primary key defined"*

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks it will be very useful. Do you have any idea about the release date of EF Core 2.1?

Comment: According to the [Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/roadmap), somewhere in [Q2 2018](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code file of context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder model_builder )
{
    base.OnModelCreating( model_builder );
    model_builder.Entity<TestTable>().HasKey(
        t => new { t.Id }
    );
}
```

So basically you just need to specify which columns can be primary key.

Comment: This is same like I thought