# How to create a tablo without primary key in entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, create-table

Entity database model insert project and than create database.But some tables not created.

I added primary key and created it again but the same tables didn't occur with primary key.

So 2 tables(don’t created 2 tables) set a primary key.But I dont solve a problem.

How to solve problem in entity?

Comment: You need to provide code. The entities and any configuration, including outlining which tables did get created, and which did not. All entities require a key defined.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key