# HasKey with expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a DbSet which database object has the key of multiple column with expression. For example, the database object (view or table) has the key of `cast(Time as Date), Col2` (Time has the type of `DateTime`). (I'm not the owner of the SQL Server database)

However, the following way to setup the key got error.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey( x => new { x.Time.Date, x.Col2 } ); // Error
```

The database object (Table or View) can have the unique constraint of

```
cast(Time as Date), Col2
```

COL2 has the type of `varchar(50)`.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? I am curious which one would allow a primary key like that.

Comment: @Igor Sql Server. I have limited permissions on the server. I don't own the database objects.

Comment: Can you script the table as a `CREATE` statement and show that? Your `HasKey` call needs to match the primary key constraint definition.

Comment: @madreflection, I understand the `HasKey` need to match the column names. However, I'm not the owner of the database object and I had to find a way to work around my the C# side.

Comment: Can you script the primary key constraint and include it in your question? (in ssms you can right click on the object and choose to generate a create script) That should clarify what the corresponding c# mapping code should be.

Comment: @Igor, I already mentioned the key of the view/table is `cast(Time as Date), Col2`

Comment: Declare the `Time` property in your entity as `System.DateTime` and use `.HasKey(x => new { x.Time, x.Col2 })`. By the time EF sees the data, it's just a column, not an expression.

Comment: You will only read this table or you need to insert, update and delete too?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho, yes, readonly.

Comment: @madreflection, you meant declare the `Date` property? Maybe `DateTime Date { get => Time.Date }`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 if my answer not work for you, please share your table script and your entity on the question.

Comment: `HasKey` is used to define the Primary Key on the table. In Sql Server a primary key can never be `cast(Time as Date)`, that is not allowed. It must always be a column value. This is why I asked you to script the table because once you provide that it becomes more clear to the rest of us what it is you are actually wanting / needing to do. So the above last edit is of no use because it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a query type is probably the right answer if you aren't updating the table, but it would be safe to simply configure the model as

```
mb.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey( x => new { x.Time, x.Col2 } );
```

EF wouldn't know about the constraint, but any attempt to violate it would simply fail at the SQL Server.

BTW in SQL Server this is either being enforced by an [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15), or an [Index on a Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15), not a regular PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: The underline table actually doesn't have any physical key. I'm trying to resolve the issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363290/mock-dbcontext-with-no-key-entity-error-on-context-myenities-addrange-how-to-i/59363683#59363683 without big change to my existing code (to use moq to mock `DbContext`)

Comment: I think your approach should work since `new { x.Time, x.Col2 }` will be unique if `new { x.Time.Date, x.Col2 }` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

As you only need to read the data of this table you can use DbQuery instead of DbSet.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbQuery<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

    //... Other tables

}
```

---

EDIT: Aparently [DbQuery is now obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbquery-1?view=efcore-3.1)

Instead of that you can use .HasNoKey(); on modelBuilder

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<MyEntity>().HasNoKey(); // No key
    }
}
```