# Why this LINQ expressoin returns the sublist with only one item

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Here is my object model.

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public Item ItemObject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LineItem> Fields { get; set; } = new List<LineItem>();
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePurchased { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The database contains **Items** and **LineItems** tables, corresponding to the object model. I am using the below written LINQ expression to retrieve an `ItemViewModel` object, provided an Item ID.

```
var i = from i in _dbContext.Items
        where i.ItemId == 123
        select new ItemViewModel
        {
            ItemObject = i,
            Fields = from field in _dbContext.LineItems
                     where field.ItemId == i.ItemId
                     select field
        };            
var viewModel = await i.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The code compiles fine but after its execution the `viewModel.Fields` property contains only one list item whereas there are three Line Items against ItemID:123, in the database table.

The SQL generated by this snippet (captured through SQL Profiler) returns three line items, through a LEFT JOIN. That means the generated SQL is fine but something is not going well with Entity Framework but I don't know what?

**Update:**
Here is the generated SQL query which correctly gives me three rows:

```
SELECT 
    [t].[ItemId], [t].[DatePurchased], 
    [s0].[ItemId], [s0].[Name]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        TOP(2) [s].[ItemId], [s].[DatePurchased]
    FROM 
        [Items] AS [s]
    WHERE 
        [s].[ItemId] = 123
    ) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [LineItems] AS [s0] ON [t].[ItemId] = [s0].[ItemId]
ORDER BY [t].[ItemId]
```

Tech stack is .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Can you provide the corresponding SQL this generates?

Comment: @John yes, I can but that would make this question unnecessarily lengthy. Do you think the generated SQL will help you anyway?

Comment: I can't be sure but it might do.

Comment: @John request granted.

Comment: Is `LineItems` **keyless** entity type? If yes, this is the second time I hear about this and I can confirm it is EFC bug. Also it not only returns 1 child per parent, but also one and the same (probably first) record, right? I can't find a bug filled in EF Core issue tracker, consider posting the issue there - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, LineItems is a keyless entity type.

Comment: @IvanStoev bug filed: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by *Ivan Stoev* in the comments under this question, the reason is a bug in Entity Framework Core, when dealing with keyless entities as a child entity. I tested it first-hand by adding a primary key to my earlier keyless table and then verifying the same LINQ statement. After adding a primary key, it starts giving me a List of 3 items, instead of only 1. So after this question and my testing, I have reported it to [EF Core issue tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20247).

For anyone who stumbles upon this question in search of answer, we have two options here. Either add a primary key to your keyless table or define a composite primary key in your EF entity model. I fixed my situation using the below line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LineItem>().HasKey(i => new { i.ItemId, i.Name });
```

It works because `LineItem.ItemId` and `LineItem.Name` combination is unique for my entities. Credit for this answer goes to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996136/12701717) (although not officially accepted answer) to an earlier SO question.