# Entity Framework 4.0, adding SQL Server view which contains no primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using Entity Framework 4.0, C# 4.0, .Net 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created the following view in my SQL Server database:

```
create view viewGetMember 
as 
    select distinct
        row_number() over (order by member.Membership_Number) ID,
        email.Communication_Point_Id id1,
        member.Membership_Number Number,
        dvt.Default_Name ParticipationStatus,
        person.Given_Name GivenName,
        person.Last_Name LastName,
        adrs.House_Number HouseNumber,
        adrs.Street Street,
        adrs.Post_Code PostCode,
        email.Email_Address EmailAddress
    from 
        Participation member
    inner join 
        Party_Participation pp on member.Participation_Id = pp.Participation_Id
    inner join 
        Party party on pp.Party_Id = party.Party_Id
    inner join 
        Individual person on party.Party_Id = person.Party_Id
    inner join 
        Domain_Value_t9n dvt on member.Participation_Status = dvt.Domain_Value_Id
    inner join 
        Communication_Point cpadrs on party.Party_Id = cpadrs.Party_Id 
    inner join 
        Communication_Point cpemail on party.Party_Id = cpemail.Party_Id
    inner join 
        [Address] adrs on cpadrs.Communication_Point_Id = adrs.Communication_Point_Id
    inner join 
        Email email on cpemail.Communication_Point_Id = email.Communication_Point_Id
    where 
        member.Membership_Number is not null 
go

select * from viewGetMember
```

In want to add this view in entity framework. However it has contain no primary in it. Though following two fields can form a composite primary key (second and third columns).

- email.Communication_Point_Id id1
- member.Membership_Number Number

I don't know how to add them as part of Entity Framework. Even I have tried adding `row_number()` (first column) as an additional column by thinking it will act as a kind of primary key but no use. Entity Framework designer is not adding this view in .edmx model file.

I have tried this by entirely removing the .edmx file and in new project only for Entity Framework but no luck. Could someone please provide me a solution to this problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of distinct when you're using ROW_NUMBER()? All the rows will be distinct anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I added distinct even before I add the row_number(). I thought row_number() would be work around for the Entity Framework's primary key requirement. But as I said, no use of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework and Sql Server view question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a perfect answer from the [Entity Framework and Sql Server view question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view-question). According to the answer given to that question the above SQL Query (view without primary key) has to be changed like following.

```
create view viewGetMember as 
select distinct
isnull(member.Membership_Number,-1) Number,
dvt.Default_Name ParticipationStatus,
person.Given_Name GivenName,
person.Last_Name LastName,
adrs.House_Number HouseNumber,
adrs.Street Street,
adrs.Post_Code PostCode,
email.Email_Address EmailAddress
from Participation member
inner join Party_Participation pp on member.Participation_Id = pp.Participation_Id
inner join Party party on pp.Party_Id = party.Party_Id
inner join Individual person on party.Party_Id = person.Party_Id
inner join Domain_Value_t9n dvt on member.Participation_Status = dvt.Domain_Value_Id
inner join Communication_Point cpadrs on party.Party_Id = cpadrs.Party_Id 
and cpadrs.Communication_Point_Type in 
(select dv.Domain_Value_Id from Domain_Value dv where dv.Short_Code = 'ADDRESS') 
inner join Communication_Point cpemail on party.Party_Id = cpemail.Party_Id 
and cpemail.Communication_Point_Type in 
(select dv.Domain_Value_Id from Domain_Value dv where dv.Short_Code = 'EMAIL') 
inner join Address adrs on cpadrs.Communication_Point_Id = adrs.Communication_Point_Id
inner join Email email on cpemail.Communication_Point_Id = email.Communication_Point_Id and cpemail.Is_Preferred = 1
where 
member.Membership_Number is not null
go
select * from viewGetMember
go
```

The thrid line `isnull(member.Membership_Number,-1) Number` makes that column as primary key and we can get rid of `row_number() over (order by member.Membership_Number) ID` or whatever we don't want to be as part of primary key.

This works well in my case.

Comment: This is not working for me on EF 5.0 but not sure if my code or EF 5.0 changes.

Comment: @Dave, I am using entity framework 5 and it is working well. However if you want to test it refresh the entities in entity framework. If possible try to simulate the same behavior in a completely new project. I hope that will work it out.

Comment: Elangesh - are your other columns besides "Membership_Number" nullable? If I add only the "isnull" to the column I want as the PK, all my columns are still added to the generated key I think because they are also not null.

Comment: @Dave, in that case you need to give NULLIF to the forcefully disable the primary key. I think following link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view

Comment: I was afraid of that. Makes for ugly SQL since a large view. Thanks!