# InvalidOperationException : 'Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection when trying toperform a Join with a .Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In a C# projet
I want to .Join(...) a view V with a table T and include subtables of T (because of lazy loading).

My code looks like this:

```cs
var query = myContext.myView
    .Join(myContext.myTable.Include(t => t.mySubTable),
        v => new { a = v.myProp },
        t => new { a = t.myProp },
        (v, t) => new { v, t }
    );
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.'

It works fine without the .Include(). The error does come from the .Include.
But the fact is that I do need this include in my case :)

Is there any way to have it to work?

Comment: Does any of your entities haven't id?

Comment: I do not see why you need `Include` here. Probably you have posted bad example.

Comment: @  
Merna Mustafa The table T does have a PK yes.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv
I need a .Include() because, later on, I need to filter this list with a clause on myTable.mySubTable so the mySubTable navigation property has to be filled in this query.

Comment: Show full query then up to materialization. What you have shown is just masking real issue.

Comment: @A.D. your view v also should have a key

Comment: @ 
Merna Mustafa
My understanding is that you cannot have PKs on views in SQL server ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438319/create-view-with-primary-key