# Adding in a primary key to an SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a view in a SQL Server database which is just a join of two tables.

Is there any way I can insert a unique primary key into the rows of this view ...or I'm not sure how I can specify one of the column names to be a primary key...any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of key?  You can use `row_number()` to generate a unique number for each row.

Comment: since it depends on the contents of the two joined tables, no not really. You can create unique identifiers ( concat two ids ) depending on the contents of those tables

Comment: Could be any type...just an integer will do.

Comment: where do I got to say this is the Primary Key?

Comment: What requirements would you have for this primary key? Would it need to be *stable*? (I.e. if a row is deleted from one or other of the tables, do all of the primary key values need to remain as they have previously been observed?) What's your actual *goal* or *problem* here?

Comment: I'm adding in a view to an entity framework model( haven't done this beofre) but I was getting some message abut needing a primary key..

Comment: It's always best to post the exact message: "some" message could be anything. And it's also helpful to state your actual problem, i.e. "I want to add a view to an EF model but I get the following error message: ...." With that additional information, it appears that your question may be a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view).

Answer (score 5):

You would have to create materialized (indexed) view in order to be able to add unique index. But you can't create PK constraint.

```
CREATE VIEW v_test
WITH SCHEMABINDING --optional
AS
    SELECT id from table

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_id
    ON v_test (id)
GO
```

Comment: I try the same but primary key of actual table is not working as primary key foe view table.