# Yii2: How to generate CRUD from MySQL/MariaDB view automatically with Gii

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I can quite easily generate a model from MySQL/MariaDB view with Gii, but when I try to generate CRUD, than I recieve the following error message:

> The table associated with frontend\models\MyModel must have primary key(s).

See also the [discussion in Yii Framework Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9544-create-a-model-and-crud-from-mysql-view-instead-of-table/page__p__299677).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is:

1. add an ID in the view, e.g. using the [CONCAT function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm),
2. overwrite the method primaryKey in the generated model.

Here is the code:

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return array('view_id');
}
```

It is not a standard solution and should be used carefully. Yii does not officially support using active record with views, because *different DBMS have different view specs and they usually don't support DB write ([2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yii/issues/1274#c0))*.

Answer (score 1):

Working on yii2,
There was issue with *primary Key*, so I search to add primary key in **VIEW TABLE** but I can't because -
[Create view with primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438319/create-view-with-primary-key)
[Adding in a primary key to an SQL view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836638/adding-in-a-primary-key-to-an-sql-view)

Then moved to create **CRUD** on **VIEW Table**. I view many articles like-

- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9544-create-a-model-and-crud-from-mysql-view-instead-of-table/
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/yii/issues/1274#c0
  so finally,

---

```
        public static function primaryKey()
        {
            return array('my_view_id');
        }
```

Worked for me.