# Circular reference when trying to serialize database

Tags: c#, json, serialization, ef-code-first

I'm trying to serialize a whole bunch of information with a lot of linked tables so I can pass it through a web service and call it with ajax. The problem I'm having is that there are some one to many relationships, and some many to many relationships and as I'm new to this I'm not sure how to stop the json following infinite loops through my database.

Is there something I am missing a script ignore on something or should I be trying to find a completely different solution?

I need all the data in PageData

```
public class SiteData
{

    public SiteData()
    {
        this.UrlResponse = new List<Response>();
    }

    public SiteData(string url, string robots, string siteMap, bool googleVerification, bool bingVerification, List<Response> urlResponse)
    {
        this.DomainUrl = url;
        this.Robots = robots;
        this.Sitemap = siteMap;
        this.GoogleVerification = googleVerification;
        this.BingVerification = bingVerification;
        this.UrlResponse = urlResponse;
    }

    public SiteData(string url)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.DomainUrl = url;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DomainUrl { get; set; }

    public string Robots { get; set; }

    public string Sitemap { get; set; }

    public bool GoogleVerification { get; set; }

    public bool BingVerification { get; set; }

    public List<Response> UrlResponse { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<PageData> PageDatas { get; set; }

}

public class PageData
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Analytics { get; set; }

    public bool Paginated { get; set; }

    public bool Flash { get; set; }

    public bool Iframe { get; set; }

    public bool NoIndexFollow { get; set; }

    public bool SchemaTag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AltTag> AltTags { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Canonical> Canonicals { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MetaTitle> MetaTitles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MetaDesc> MetaDescs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogLocation> BlogLocations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H1> H1s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H2> H2s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<H3> H3s { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ViewState> ViewStates { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("DomainUrl")]
    public SiteData DomainUrl { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<SiteData> SiteData { get; set; }
}

public class Platform
{
    public Platform() { }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string PlatformExtension { get; set; }

    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class AltTag
{
    public AltTag() { }

    public AltTag(int id, string altTag)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.AltTagString = altTag;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string AltTagString { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class Canonical
{
    public Canonical() { }

    public Canonical(int id, string altTag)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.CanonicalString = altTag;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string CanonicalString { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class MetaTitle
{
    public MetaTitle() { }

    public MetaTitle(int id, string metaTitle)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.MetaTitleString = metaTitle;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string MetaTitleString { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class MetaDesc
{
    public MetaDesc() { }

    public MetaDesc(int id, string metaDesc)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.MetaDescString = metaDesc;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string MetaDescString { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class BlogLocation
{
    public BlogLocation() { }

    public BlogLocation(int id, string blog)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.BlogLoc = blog;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string BlogLoc { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class H1
{
    public H1() { }

    public H1(int id, string h1)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.H1String = h1;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string H1String { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class H2
{
    public H2() { }

    public H2(int id, string h2)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.H2String = h2;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string H2String { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class H3
{
    public H3() { }

    public H3(int id, string h3)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.H3String = h3;
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public string H3String { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class ViewState
{
    public ViewState()
    {
        this.Existance = new bool();
    }

    [Key]
    public int KeyId { get; set; }

    public bool Existance { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageData")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual PageData PageData { get; set; }
}
```

The actual call:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetPage(string pageId)
    {
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {   
            PageData page = db.PageDatas.Find(Int32.Parse(pageId));

            string json = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            json = jss.Serialize(page);

            return json;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Map the required data to DTOs first...?

Comment: I need everything except the SiteData stuff, isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A database is just how you store your information. It has not much to do with how you present that information to the user.

There's no need to make things any more complex than they have to be. What do you show the user? Probably just grids and detail pages, maybe input forms, right?

So provide ways to read only the data you need to show, and to only update the data you need to update.

Here's an example: say you have a grid that you must fill up with data. Rather than fetch data with relationships etc., just fetch a list of rows and bind that list to the grid. One easy way to do this with Entity Framework is to create a VIEW in the database containing only those fields you want to show, then map that VIEW to an Entity in Entity Framework, and then querying that Entity. Grids are read-only anyway (editable grids are completely unnecessary and often very confusing for end users) and you simplify data retrieval this way.

Similarly, for detail pages and even input forms you can provide VIEWs that only contain the data you need to show. For filling up drop-down lists in input forms you can simply read the required entity's values with a simple query.

See also the following links:

- [Entity Framework and SQL Server View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013333/entity-framework-and-sql-server-view)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d834520-8643-4ada-955a-8173178880f4/generate-views-in-entity-framework-50-code-first
- http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/01/31/Building-an-Entity-Framework-40-model-on-views-practical-tips.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: As I stated in the question, I need to show everything in PageData. I understand how views work; I don't feel like this was particularly related to my question. However I appreciate you for taking the time to write it.