# Lightswitch using editable Grid which uses View as data source

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to develop a screen in Light-Switch, in which data shown is combined from 3 or 4 tables. But the Controls becomes read only for this view.

I don't know how can I achieve this type of functionality in Light-Switch.

Is is possible the make totally custom editable Grid which has custom Save method to save the edited values in related tables?

Note: When I work on single table it works fine.

**Edit:**

To simulate the issue, just create a view that returns the rows from 3/4 tables by using Union, for e.g.:

```
Select Col1, Col2 Col3 from Table1 where Active=1
UNION
Select Col1, Col2 Col3 from Table2 where Date>GetDate()
UNION
Select Name as Col1, Col2 Col3 from Table3
```

Now pass this view to LightSwitch to be edited in grid.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code to understand it better.

Comment: The real code is very big & DB size is also big. But the problem can be simulated easily. see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following the following article:

[Using WCF RIA Service in LightSwitch](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-use-wcf-ria-service-in-lightswitch-2012/)

But had problems making Grid Editable.

After looking for the solution around the net. I found the following URL that solved my issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208573/1400290